# compare values from 2 nested dictionaries in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing, dictionary, flatten

I'm looking for suggestions on best approach in comparing json files using python3 and outputting matching key, value pairs

I have scripted python to loop through json data taken through several api requests and then create 2 new json files with nested dictionaries and lists. The 2 json outputs I have created basically contain information about "objects" pertaining to 2 different "projects" - importantly the object Names and object Identifiers.  The arbitrary output json/list of nested dictionaries, would typically look something like this:

```
projectA:[
        {dashboardName: "v1",
        dashboardID: "v2",
        dashbTabs:[
            {dashTabName: "v3",
            dashTabID; "v4",
            reports:[
                {reportName: "v5",
                reportID: "v6",
                metrics:[
                    {metricName: "v7",
                    metricID: "v8"
                    },
                    {metricName:v9",
                    metricID: "v10"...
```

And so on for multiple metrics, reports, and dashboards

Now that I have the above json outputs for each of the 2 projects, I need to find out if any of the IDs in projectA are the same as the IDs in projectB. If so I need to know the "path" of the objects with matching IDs.

Although help with code would be greatly appreciated (I am not a fluent coder) I am looking for suggestions on approach to achieve this.  I have considered flattening the files first to get a list of all IDs and paths of these and then doing the comparison of IDs.  Or alternatively looping through all IDs in projectB and checking for matching IDs in projectA.  Or perhaps there is a better/faster way to do this?

I think a csv output would make sense where I have one column with "path" from projectA and another column with path from projectB e.g

```
col1                                           col2  
dashboardName:v1/dashTabName:v3/reportName:v5  dashboardName:v1
```

Note in this example it would be a dashboardID in projectB which is the same as a reportID in projectA

Comment: I wrote a recursive python function a while back to pop items from a dictionary based on the nested keys in another dictionary. Might be a good starting point? [recursive_dict_pop()](https://github.com/dijksterhuis/useful-python)

Comment: Excuse the horrendous tab sizes.